# How does the lower-explosion-limit (LEL) of gasoline depend on O2 concentration?

Tags: explosions, combustion

The lower-explosion-limit (equal to lower-flameable-limit) of gasoline is 1.4 vol.-%. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flammability_limit)

I assume that this value derived for the mixture between gasoline vapor with air (21 % O2). I expect that when the oxygen concentration is reduced, the LEL will increase. In the absence of O2 combustion would even be impossible.

In my application I consider the mixing of:
- gasoline combustion products (mainly CO2, H2O)
- unburned gasoline vapour (gasoline might be cracked by temperature, bu for simplicity lets assume that it is still in original composition), 
- and air (O2, N2)

Do you have a correlation how the LEL of gasoline depends on oxygen content?

Comment: Not specifically for gasoline, but https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/mining/userFiles/works/pdfs/tloca.pd discusses lower- and upper-flammibility levels vs limiting oxygen concentration (LOC) for fuel/air/inert gas mixtures. Now, were I your safety person, I would insist that you assume no combustion occurred to set your limits (worst case fuel/air mixture).

Comment: Thanks for your link Jon.  (Short note for other readers, you need to add an 'f' at the end of the link).   Agree to you worst case statement. In my case the gas mixture comes for a gasoline engine in significant rich operation (to little oxygen).   Therefore I can estimate the ratio between   combustion products and gasoline vapor.   First calculations are to find out the sensitivity of the results based on different assumptions (e.g. for LEL). (And for my deeper understanding of the subject). My final findings will be reviewed from a professional safety institution.

Comment: Oops! Looks like I deserve an 'F' for that link...

Comment: @BerndGit, do you have an application in mind?  If so, please provide a few details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the key-word LOC Jon Cluster has provided, I was able to find this interesting paper:
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/prs.680170305

My main takeaway from this paper is, that the LEL might only be slightly increased even at added intert gas as big as 20 %. So in my engineering application, I do not see much potential in unilitsation of this increase of LEL. So I'll stay with teh LEL of gasoline in air.